# didSelectAnnotationView call after viewForAnnotation in iOS6

Tags: ios, mapkit

I'm using MapKit in iOS 5 and the function `didSelectAnnotationView` is correctly called before `viewForAnnotation`. However, in iOS 6, `didSelectAnnotationView` gets called after `viewForAnnotation`. How do I fix it?

Comment: Have you found a fix for this?  Or at least understood what was going on?

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure this is what's happening? I had code that was leading me to the same conclusion initially, until I set my breakpoints in other locations.

If your `didSelectAnnotationView` (at some point) calls the map view's `addAnnotation` then it is possible your log messages or breakpoints are misleading you.

The difference I HAVE noticed between iOS5 and iOS6 is that when `addAnnotation` is used, in iOS5 there is a delay before `viewForAnnotation` is called whereas in iOS6 it happens immediately. I had to change the order of operations in my code (so that `addAnnotation` is called last), but otherwise the same code works for both versions of iOS.